# Are these statements about wedge sum true?

Tags: general-topology

Since there's no concrete explanation on wedge sum in my text, I have proven following basic statements on my own. I want to know whether I proved correct things. First of all, here is the definition of wedge sum.

> Let $\{X_i\}_{i\in I}$ be a family of topological spaces.
>
> Fix $p\in \prod_{i\in I} X_i$
>
> Then $\bigwedge_{i\in I} X_i \triangleq (\coprod_{i\in I} X_i)/(p_i,p_j)$.

Belows are what I have proven:

> Define $\phi_i: X_i \rightarrow \coprod_{i\in I} X_i:x\mapsto (x,i)$.
>
> Let $\pi:\coprod_{i\in I}X_i \rightarrow \bigwedge_{i\in I} X_i:x\rightarrow [x]$ be the projection map.
>
> Then, (1) If $|I|≧2$, then $\bigcap_{i\in I} \pi\circ\phi_i(X_i)$ is a singleton.
>
> (2) $\pi\circ\phi_i(X_i)\cong X_i$

Are these true?

Comment: Note that the wedge sum of spaces $X$ and $Y$ is (confusingly) denoted $X \vee Y$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

2) Follows from the fact that $\pi\circ\phi_i$ is open, continuous bijection.

1) I am slightly confused about this one since $\pi^{-1}(\bigcap_i \pi\circ\phi_i(X_i))=\bigcap_i \pi^{-1}\circ\pi\circ\phi_i(X_i)=\bigcap_i \phi_i(X_i) = \emptyset$ **[This is wrong. Look at comments]**

Notice that another way to get at the wedge is to attach $X_i$ to $\bigvee_j X_j$ one at a time via the attaching map:
$$f \colon \{p_i\} \subseteq X_i \longrightarrow \bigvee_{j \neq i} X_j$$

In such a case: 
$$\bigvee_i X_i = \left(\bigsqcup_i\pi(X_i-\{p_i\})\right)\bigsqcup\pi(X_1)$$

Comment: I'm afraid to say that you assertion for (1) is wrong. $\pi^{-1}\circ\pi(A)\neq A$

Comment: Is it trivial that $\pi\circ\phi$ is open? I proved that by separating cases. Also, is $\pi\circ\phi_i$ often used, so that I can name them as "the canonical map"?

Comment: @Rubertos Ah, right. In fact its precisely $\{p_j\}\cup\phi_i(X_i)$. Which proves your point

Comment: @Rubertos That projections are open requires proof. But inclusion to disjoint union is so by definition.